# Color Conditional Formatting on dataframe deploying in streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-formatting, streamlit

After executing the code, multiple entries in the transposed columns are being conditionally highlighted.

I only want to highlight the top value and bottom value in each transposed column.

Below is the code for reference:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'E0': ["Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4"],
    'E1': [10, 20, 3, 5],
    'E2': [25, None, 20, 1],
    'E3': [5, 10, 8, None]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_transposed = df.transpose()
custom_text = 'Not Available'
df_filled = df_transposed.fillna(custom_text)

def highlight_top(val):
    if val == df_transposed.loc['E1'].max() or val == df_transposed.loc['E2'].max() or val == df_transposed.loc['E3'].max():
        return 'background-color: green; color: white;'
    else:
        return ''

def highlight_bot(val):
    if val == df_transposed.loc['E1'].min() or val == df_transposed.loc['E2'].min() or val == df_transposed.loc['E3'].min():
        return 'background-color: red; color: white;'
    else:
        return ''

# Applying the style to the transposed DataFrame
styled_df = df_filled.style.applymap(highlight_top).applymap(highlight_bot)
st.table(styled_df)
```

Output Table:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`describe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) to get the `min`/`max`, then [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) a predefined CSS styles :

```
CSS = "background-color:{bc}; color:{c}" # add more if needed

STATS = {"min": {"stat": "min", "bc": "red", "c": "white"},
         "max": {"stat": "max", "bc": "green", "c": "white"}}

def highlight_mm(df_tos, stat, bc, c):
    # global df
    import numpy as np
    desc = df.drop(columns="E0").describe()
    mask = df_tos.eq(desc.loc[stat], axis=0)
    return np.where(mask, CSS.format(bc=bc, c=c), "")

styled_df = (
    df_filled.style
        .apply(highlight_mm, **STATS["min"], axis=None)
        .apply(highlight_mm, **STATS["max"], axis=None)    
        .format(precision=2) # this one is optional
)

st.table(styled_df)
```

*NB : This code replaces the lines 17 to 31 of yours.*

Output (*in Streamlit*) :

[image]